# Disk Utility First Aid has no progress bar?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility

It is on "Checking snapshot 1 of 4" and has been for 30 minutes.

There is no progress bar. The drive is a 1TB SATA drive.

Should I quit it and start it again or just let it chug?

Comment: how big is the drive

Comment: even at maximum read speed of 700 MB/Sec it would take  25 minutes just to read your disk (no repairs)

Comment: The adage I work by is that your patience ought to be directly proportional to the time since your last backup;)

Answer (score 1):

It was indeed stuck. We ended up force quitting the process.

It appears from other testing that the drive is operating at a much reduce top speed. Hopefully it is not failing. But this process was definitely stuck.